# Go To Controller in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

My controllers are located in a non-standard location in another class library. Is there a way I can make the "Go To Controller" short cut on a view find these?

[image: Go To Controller example]

Comment: @pluc see screenshot in edit.

Comment: Oh... I've never seen that before! Well the answer is most likely No because the ASP.NET MVC additions to Visual Studio sits on naming conventions, and moving your controllers to another project breaks that naming convention. I doubt there is a solution to this unfortunatly.